# How to set the user and group for a set of autogenerated files

Tags: linux, sphinx

I am not sure whether this is a Sphinx question or a Linux question.

Anyway, I am running Sphinx on my CentOS server box.

I successfully managed to change the ownership of some Sphinx-related files and directories as I want only root and the Apache group to be able to read those information:

```
chown root.apache /etc/sphinx/sphinx.conf
chmod 640 /etc/sphinx/sphinx.conf

chown -R root.apache /var/lib/sphinx
chmod -R 750 /var/lib/sphinx
```

My problem is when Sphinx generates the files containing the index in the directory /var/lib/sphinx, they have ownership

```
root:root
```

How can I make them have permission

```
root:apache
```

?

The Sphinx documentation doesn't mention about that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set SETGID for directory /var/lib/sphinx/:

```
root@centos:~# chmod g+s /var/lib/sphinx/
```

This way, all created file in directory /var/lib/sphinx/ will inherit group from parent.
If sphinx is not messing with ownership by it self (I guess it't not) then this will work.

You can read more [here](http://www.gnu.org/s/coreutils/manual/html_node/Directory-Setuid-and-Setgid.html) about SETGID on directories.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can run the cron job as the user `sphinx` rather than as `root`, either by adding `sudo -u sphinx` in the existing crontab entry, or by removing it from `root`'s crontab and adding it to the appropriate user's crontab. (Perhaps you should report this as a bug against the package, if you are using a packaged version.)